# Trying to dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04.02 but installer can't find it

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-8

I've read a lot of questions from people who have the same problem as me however there results didn't work for me.
So I've already manually partitioned but it doesn't even see that either. It sees my SSD partitions but can't see my HDD.
I'd like to try other ways to install Ubuntu like partition it from the USB. But I have 2 built in HDDs
The new partition I've made on my HDD isn't formatted either so I can't really see what's wrong here.

Thanks in advanced for the help

EDIT: After reading some other answers I have found that I should disable Intel Smart Response Technology, I am going to do that now.

EDIT2: Ok I'm currently in the live session and I found that Ubuntu CAN see the partitions just fine but in the installer it won't, any ideas?

Comment: hmmm. I'll give the options a go. Thanks for showing me the post!

Comment: Thanks! Solved it, as it turned out it Ubuntu was reading the GPT partition.